# Remove ActivityId from WCF Request

Tags: wcf, web-services, interop

I'm having an interesting compatibility issue between a WCF client and a Java web service. In short I've found that the way the header is generated is causing the problem - the ActivityId and Action elements in the header as well as what WCF is doing with the namespace of the custom header is causing issues. I've successfully consumed the WSDL with wsdl.exe, but WCF seems to be manipulating the header in a way that the Java web service doesn't like. Is there any way I can set up the bindings for the WCF client to not send the ActivityId and Action elements?

Comment: Can you show us the client side generated config?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you have tracing turned on in the client? I think that is what is adding the activity ID as its trying to flow the tracing activity to the service for end to end tracing. Turn off the activity tracing flag and it should go - see my comment for the action header

Comment: it was the tracing adding those elements; disabling tracing helped fix the issue. The Java web service didn't interpret the SOAP message very well (some kind of weird namespace issue).

Comment: How do you turn it off?  WHere is it turned off?

Comment: @irperez I've narrowed down the settings which need to be deactivated to remove the `ActivityId` SOAP header.

Answer (score 5):

This issue commonly occurs when a WCF client attempts to connect to a non-WCF server, e.g. JAX-WS, Websphere etc.

Just to add to Richard's lifesaver answer and address @irperez's comment, the actual settings which need to be disabled to prevent WCF diagnostics from adding `ActivityId` during WCF Diagnostic Tracing are to remove:

- Remove `ActivityTracing` from `switchvalue`
- Set `propagateActivity` to `false`

i.e. Change

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
...
```

To:

```
<source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information" 
        propagateActivity="false">
  <listeners>
    <add name="xml"/>
  </listeners>
```

If the `ActivityId` is enabled, it injects the below into the SOAP headers, which can break unsuspecting servers:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="5de75017-da08-4ac2-84f2-5374953cc2a1" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">
      9f076849-e76e-4675-84c1-5026b1c2eb1a
    </ActivityId>
  </s:Header>
```