# How to Throw WCF Exception with Customized Soap Header and Body

Tags: wcf, exception, soapheader, soapfault

1. I know how to use [FaultException] and throw Customized [DataContract] in WCF
2. I know how to return soap message with Customized Headers and Body Tags using [MessageContract]

However, I'm going to ask: How to throw a [FaultException] in WCF with customized Headers and Body? Because when I use [FaultException] to throw [MessageContract], it always wraps my headers and body tags into  body tag.

This is not what I want. Most of the SOAP clients do not understand WCF [FaultException].

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-CH" />
      <detail>
        <CustomizedError xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PlayWcfFault" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <BodyTag1>Hello BodyTag1</BodyTag1>
          <HeaderTag1>Hello HeaderTag1</HeaderTag1>
        </CustomizedError>
      </detail>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

```
    [MessageContract]
    public class CustomizedError
    {
        [MessageHeader] public string HeaderTag1;
        [MessageBodyMember] public string BodyTag1;
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [FaultContract(typeof(CustomizedError))]
        CustomizedError GetData();
    }

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public CustomizedError GetData()
        {
            CustomizedError fault = new CustomizedError
            {
                HeaderTag1 = "Hello HeaderTag1",
                BodyTag1 = "Hello BodyTag1",
            };
            throw new FaultException<CustomizedError>(fault, "");
            // return fault;
        }

    }
```

The soap message I want is

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
          <HeaderTag1>Hello HeaderTag1</HeaderTag1>
</s:Header >
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
          <BodyTag1>Hello BodyTag1</BodyTag1>
      </detail>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am confused that why you define the soap message structure in that format. But as far as I know, the IErrorHandler interface is able to custom the fault message when capturing the communication error.  Here is an example used to capture the errors during communication.

[Hadler Error EndPoint in my host - WCF - Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512991/hadler-error-endpoint-in-my-host-wcf-behaviour/55530509#55530509)

We are capable of adding the custom message header in the ProvideFault method. Please consider the below code.

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {
            FaultException faultException = new FaultException(error.Message);
            MessageFault messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, error.Message);
            MessageHeader mh = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("itemname", "apptest", "34");
            fault.Headers.Add(mh);
        }
```

Result.
[image]

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.
**Updated.**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:4386");
            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

            using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(TestService), uri))
            {
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), binding, "");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                    {
                        HttpGetEnabled = true
                    };

                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                }
                Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");


                sh.Opened += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("service is ready");
                };
                sh.Closed += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("service is closed");
                };
                sh.Open();

                Console.ReadLine();

                sh.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int Div(int x, int y);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior]
    public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        public int Div(int x, int y)
        {
            if (y == 0)
            {
                FaultReason reason = new FaultReason("The divisor cannot be Zero");
                FaultCode code = new FaultCode("NotZero", "mynamespace",new FaultCode("mysubcode"));
                throw new FaultException(reason,code);
            }
            return x / y;
        }
}
```

In order to create ActivityID field, we should enable tracing and message logging on the server-side.

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" propagateActivity="true" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="xmlLog" initializeData="myLogs.svclog"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"/>
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Link.**
[About ActivityID field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004244/remove-activityid-from-wcf-request)
[Configure tracing and message logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging)
When the invocation on the client-side passes a parameter 0. We capture the http request by using fiddler.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Abraham Qian. It is very close to the requirement! I need to have a WCF application which is able to throw this format of soap: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wstep/7513a8c0-9a4b-48df-b474-ceb3cbd86dcc

Comment: This could be achieved by using the WCF service created with wshttpbinding. Then we throw a custom Faultexception. Please refer to my updated reply.